# Permitir solo numeros negativos en asptxtbox usando keypress o regex

Tags: javascript, regex

necesito aplicar dos restricciones en unos textboxs para que acepten solamente valores negativos.
Y dependiendo del textbox, que acepte hasta cierto valor(por ejemplo hasta -1000 en uno, -2000 en otro, etc).

Alguna idea? tengo este keypress que solo acepta numeros:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       function OnlyNumber(evt){
         var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
         if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
              return false;    
           return true;
       }
   </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que tu código solo acepte valores negativos debes comprobar si en la primera posición se ingresa el "-" cuyo keyCode el 45

```js
function OnlyNumber(evt,min){
   var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
   if(evt.target.value.length == 0){
     return charCode == 45;
   }
   else if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
   {
     return false;   
   }
     return min == null ? true : Number(evt.target.value+evt.key)>=min;
 }
```

```html
<label>Acepto solo Num negativos</label><br />
<input onkeypress="return OnlyNumber(event)" /><br />

<label>Acepto solo Num negativos que sean mayores que -1000</label><br />
<input onkeypress="return OnlyNumber(event,-1000)" />
```